# mysql select all from two different tables with different column

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Select all from two different tables with different column name and print the result in one HTML table using PHP.

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT* from tbl_staff where db_user='$user'
uninon 
SELECT* from tbl_activities where db_transferredto='$name'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

**Error:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'uninon SELECT* from tbl_activities where db_transferredto='
>   mohamad salimi'' at line 2

Comment: its `union` not `uninon`

Comment: Give space between `select` and `*` `SELECT *`

Comment: `$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from tbl_staff where db_user='$user' union SELECT * from tbl_activities where db_transferredto='$name'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: Do the column names, amount and data types match?

Comment: yes its UNION biscuit not uninon biscuit.

Comment: user2468160 no it's not match

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Keyword is `UNION` not `uninon`
- There should be space between SELECT and * (SELECT * )
- Don't use * while using UNION unless the columns are same.

---

**Example**

```
SELECT name,description from tableA    
UNION    
SELECT name,description from tableB
```

Comment: can we do it for 2 different tables in column name and type and number ?! or any other method ?!

Comment: Yeah you can do it on two different tables, but with same number of columns